# How to keep streamlit ag-grid selected rows after page update?

Tags: python, pandas, ag-grid, streamlit

I'm currently working on a real-time metrics dashboard with an AgGrid table to display the data. To keep the data up-to-date, I would like to reload it automatically every 15 seconds. I've tried using `st_autorefresh` to accomplish this, but I'm facing an issue where the AgGrid table loses the selected rows after each page update, even when using `pre_selected_rows`.

Do any of you have experience with this issue and know how to solve it?

Here's the link for the example repository:

https://github.com/andrewssobral/streamlit-example

Here's the link of the running application:

https://andrewssobral-streamlit-example-streamlit-app-txrvx1.streamlit.app/

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

from streamlit_autorefresh import st_autorefresh
from st_aggrid import GridOptionsBuilder, AgGrid, GridUpdateMode, DataReturnMode, JsCode

if 'pre_selected_rows' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.pre_selected_rows = []

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'STATUS'])
df['ID'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['STATUS'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3))
st.write(df)

# get pre-selected rows from session state
pre_selected_rows = st.session_state.pre_selected_rows
st.write("pre_selected_rows: ", st.session_state.pre_selected_rows)

# use the pre-selected rows when building the grid options
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gb.configure_default_column(editable=True, wrapText=True, autoHeight=True)
gb.configure_column('ID', minWidth=80, maxWidth=80, type=["numericColumn","numberColumnFilter"], sortable=True, sort='desc', checkboxSelection=True, headerCheckboxSelection=True)
gb.configure_column('STATUS', minWidth=100, maxWidth=100)
gb.configure_pagination(paginationAutoPageSize=False, paginationPageSize=3)
gb.configure_side_bar()
gb.configure_selection('multiple', pre_selected_rows=pre_selected_rows, use_checkbox=True)
gb_grid_options = gb.build()

# render the grid and get the selected rows
grid_return = AgGrid(
        df,
        gridOptions = gb_grid_options,
        key = 'ID',
        reload_data = True,
        data_return_mode = DataReturnMode.AS_INPUT,
        update_mode = GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED, # GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED or GridUpdateMode.VALUE_CHANGED or 
        allow_unsafe_jscode = True,
        fit_columns_on_grid_load = False,
        enable_enterprise_modules = False,
        height = 320,
        width = '100%',
        theme = "streamlit"
    )
selected_rows = grid_return["selected_rows"]

# save the row indexes of the selected rows in the session state
pre_selected_rows = []
for selected_row in selected_rows:
        pre_selected_rows.append(selected_row['_selectedRowNodeInfo']['nodeRowIndex'])
st.session_state.pre_selected_rows = pre_selected_rows

# print the selected rows
st.write("Selected rows: ", selected_rows)

st_autorefresh(interval=((1*15*1000)), key="dataframerefresh")
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a great way to do this if you are periodically refreshing the page. If the page isn't actually reloading (and you're just reloading the data), you can store the user's selected rows in the [session state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state).

The issue is that if the current session ends/the page fully reloads, anything stored in the session state would be lost. In that case, you would be better off storing the selected rows in a database (could be as simple as a [Google Sheet](https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/databases/private-gsheet)), and retrieving that data when the page loads so you can properly display the selected rows for the user. You'd probably want to associate the selected rows with some type of user ID such as an email address – you can use [st.experimental_user](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/personalization/st.experimental_user) for this since it looks like you're using Streamlit Community Cloud.

Comment: Hello Caroline, thanks for your feedback. However, if you take a look on the running application, the selected rows still in the session state, look at this: https://andrewssobral-streamlit-example-streamlit-app-txrvx1.streamlit.app/ (you can click on the ag-grid checkbox and in the next refresh it shows the selected rows stores in the session state). I also have put the link to the source code in my post. Using st_autofresh does not refresh the fully page. Do you have any idea how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to update an AG-grid using pre-selected rows from session state and couldn't get it to work.
What you could try alternatively is something like this:

- don't use pre-selected rows but add a boolean column to your dataframe, for example ['Selected']
- Show the column in AG-Grid with a checkbox to select/deselect https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/checkboxes-for-boolean-columns-in-aggrid/35152
- change background of AG-Grid rows depending on value in 'Selected'
- update session state if value in 'Selected' column is changed in AG-Grid and change dataframe column 'Selected' according to session state.

Here is an example of your code with these changes applied:

Please note that though the session state of the selected rows is updated immediately after the grid is changed, the refreshing of the selection in AG-Grid is only done according to your time settings in st.autorefresh, in this example after 2 seconds.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

from streamlit_autorefresh import st_autorefresh
from st_aggrid import GridOptionsBuilder, AgGrid, GridUpdateMode, DataReturnMode, JsCode

if 'selected_rows_array' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.selected_rows_array=[False,False,False]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'STATUS'])
df['ID'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['STATUS'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3))
# Dataframe gets additional column 'Selected' which is updated with every refresh according to the session state of selected rows
df.insert(loc=0, column='Selected', value=st.session_state.selected_rows_array)

# Show dataframe without column 'Selected'
st.write(df[['ID','STATUS']])

# add a placeholder to show the session state of the selected_rows_array
# the placeholder gets updated at the bottom as soon as the grid changed
placeholder = st.empty()
placeholder.write("Session State selected_rows_array:  "+str(list(st.session_state.selected_rows_array)))

# checkbox renderer for checkbox
checkbox_renderer = JsCode("""
        class CheckboxRenderer{
        init(params) {
            this.params = params;
            this.eGui = document.createElement('input');
            this.eGui.type = 'checkbox';
            this.eGui.checked = params.value;
            this.checkedHandler = this.checkedHandler.bind(this);
            this.eGui.addEventListener('click', this.checkedHandler);
        }
        checkedHandler(e) {
            let checked = e.target.checked;
            let colId = this.params.column.colId;
            this.params.node.setDataValue(colId, checked);
        }
        getGui(params) {
            return this.eGui;
        }
        destroy(params) {
        this.eGui.removeEventListener('click', this.checkedHandler);
        }
        }//end class
    """)
# rowStyle renderer for different background for selected rows
rowStyle_renderer = JsCode("""
        function(params) {
            if (params.data.Selected) {
                return {
                    'color': 'black',
                    'backgroundColor': 'pink'
                }
            }
            else {
                return {
                    'color': 'black',
                    'backgroundColor': 'white'
                }
            }
        }; 
    """)

gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gb.configure_default_column(editable=True, wrapText=True, autoHeight=True)
# gb.configure_column('ID', minWidth=80, maxWidth=80, type=["numericColumn","numberColumnFilter"], sortable=True, sort='desc', checkboxSelection=True, headerCheckboxSelection=True)
gb.configure_column('ID', minWidth=80, maxWidth=80, type=["numericColumn","numberColumnFilter"], sortable=True, sort='desc', checkboxSelection=False, headerCheckboxSelection=False)
gb.configure_column( 'Selected',headerName=' ', minWidth=80, maxWidth=80, editable=True, cellRenderer=checkbox_renderer)
gb.configure_column('STATUS', minWidth=100, maxWidth=100)
gb.configure_pagination(paginationAutoPageSize=False, paginationPageSize=3)
gb.configure_side_bar()
# gb.configure_selection('multiple', pre_selected_rows=pre_selected_rows, use_checkbox=True)
gb.configure_selection('multiple', use_checkbox=False)

gb_grid_options = gb.build()
# rowStyle added
gb_grid_options['getRowStyle'] = rowStyle_renderer


# render the grid and get the selected rows
grid_return = AgGrid(
        df,
        gridOptions = gb_grid_options,
        key = 'ID',
        reload_data = True,
        data_return_mode = DataReturnMode.AS_INPUT,
        update_mode = GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED, # GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED or GridUpdateMode.VALUE_CHANGED or
        allow_unsafe_jscode = True,
        fit_columns_on_grid_load = False,
        enable_enterprise_modules = False,
        height = 320,
        width = '100%',
        theme = "streamlit"
    )

# save the array of column 'Selected' in the session state and update display of placeholder
if not np.array_equal(st.session_state.selected_rows_array,grid_return['data']['Selected']):
    st.session_state.selected_rows_array=grid_return['data']['Selected']
    placeholder.empty()
    placeholder.write("Session State selected_rows_array:  "+str(list(st.session_state.selected_rows_array)))

st_autorefresh(interval=((1*2*1000)), key="dataframerefresh")
```